# Vue + Laravel API CRUD - Problem with the update method

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to create a basic CRUD app with Laravel 9 and Vue js 3. My problem is that method seems to be not functioning properly at all.

Update method from the Laravel API works fine (I tested this in postman and it works well).

So I think the problem lies within on of my methods or variables? The handleUpdate() function seems to be not catching the values of the contact variable (contact.name, contact. email...)

On page load, it retrieves all the properties of the contact array, but it returns a 500 internal server error upon saving it. Does it have something to do with the handleUpdate?

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
<template>
   <h1>EDIT EMPLOYEE INFORMATION</h1>
   <p>Profile for {{ contact.name }}</p>

<form @submit.prevent="handleUpdate" class="mt-5">
  <label>User Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="contact.name" required>
  <label>Email Address</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="contact.email" required>
  <label>Job Title</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="contact.job_title">
  <label>Contact No.</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="contact.contact_no">
  <button>Edit User</button>
</form>
</template>

<script>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    name: 'EditView',
    setup() {

    const route = useRoute()
    const error = ref('')
    const contact = ref({})

    const getContactById = async () => {
        
    try{
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/get_contact/${route.params.id}`)
        contact.value = res.data
      }
      catch(err){
        error.value = err.message
        console.log(error.value)
      }
    }

    const handleUpdate = async () => {        
        try{
            await axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/api/update_contact/${route.params.id}`, 
            {
                name: contact.name,
                email: contact.email,
                job_title: contact.job_title,
                contact_no: contact.contact_no
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
            })
            .then(() => router.push({ name: 'home'}))                
            }
            catch(err){
                error.value = err.message
            }
    }

    onMounted(() => {
        getContactById()
        console.log(contact.value)
    })

    return { contact, handleUpdate }
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: Check your logs in `storage/logs`. Could be a number of things like missing CSRF token, wrong HTTP method, etc.

Comment: this is a post method and no authentication yet

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a **PHP** script (so not the Vue script you've shown). Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message. Also check your Laravel logs in `storage/logs` to see if there's any information there.

Comment: but the request works in postman and I was able to update it. so I was thinking if the problem lies within vue?

Comment: It could be something that Vue is sending, but it's not what is actually generating the error. An HTTP 500 is generated by the server you're sending the request to. The Laravel and server logs should tell you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like to problem really lies in the vue file.

I was not able to pass the contact variable from the handleUpdate method. Passing the contact variable, and everything seems to be working fine now.

```
<form @submit.prevent="handleUpdate(CONTACT)" class="mt-5">
  <label>User Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="contact.name" required>
  <label>Email Address</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="contact.email" required>
  <label>Job Title</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="contact.job_title">
  <label>Contact No.</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="contact.contact_no">
  <button>Edit User</button>
</form>
</template>
```

also for this method:

```
const handleUpdate = async (CONTACT) => {        

        try{
            const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/api/update_contact/${route.params.id}`, 
            {
                name: contact.name,
                email: contact.email,
                job_title: contact.job_title,
                contact_no: contact.contact_no                
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
                // console.log(editName.value)
            })
            .then(() => router.push({ name: 'home'}))                
            }
            catch(err){
                error.value = err.message
            }
    }
```